# Importing from bigquery to google sheets limits to 10k rows

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to import a table from google bigquery to google sheets.
DATA > DATA CONNECTORS > BIG QUERY
but when I import it it says LIMITED to 10,000 rows.

Is there any way to pass that limit?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, according to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/g-suite/connecting-bigquery-and-google-sheets-to-help-with-hefty-data-analysis), the BigQuery Sheets connector has a limit of 10,000 rows. Although, there is a work around for this limit, in case you want to overcome it.

You can use Google Cloud Storage (GCS) as a staging ground. So, you can export your data to GCS as a .csv file, then import it in Google Sheets. Below the steps are described:

1. Exporting data from BigQuery to a .csv on Google Cloud Storage (GCS)

- You can export your table to GCS manually using the console, using gcloud command or one of the available API's, [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#exporting_table_data).
- I must point that you need to have the required permissions to export data to GCS. Also, pay attention to the limitations: you can export up to 1GB to a single data file, also the destination of the export has to be Cloud Storage.

2. Google Cloud Storage to Google Sheets using Google Cloud Functions

- In order to import your .csv file to Google Sheets, you can create a Cloud Function which every time a new .csv file is uploaded to GCS, it is also exported to Google Sheets.
- These following tutorials do exactly what I mentioned above, you can simply follow one of them, [link 1](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-function2sheet/index.html?index=..%2F..index#0) and [link 2](https://medium.com/google-cloud/a-cloud-function-to-automate-google-spreadsheet-csv-import-d2ffb8fbe9b4).

Doing so,you will be able to query all your data using Google Sheets and overcome the limitation of 10,000 rows with the BigQuery Sheets connector.